# GCM App needs to be uninstalled after moving to FCM without migration?

Tags: android, firebase

My Client lost their GCM account Google email address, So they have to make new Firebase Google Account for April 11, 2019, transition.

If GCM app upgraded to FCM app, GCM token of the app already exists.
So it cannot generate new FCM token even though it is FCM supported app, SO it can't receive FCM push message after Aprill 11 2019?

In short, do we need to uninstall the GCM app and install the FCM app to receive FCM push when it is not migrated to FCM? or Upgrading is enough?

Answer (score 0):

I found that just upgrading gcm app to firebase app is enough with no migration.